# Multiple Countif Statements

Tags: excel, connection-string, excel-formula, range, countif

I'm trying to create a countif formula on a range of data.  I have 4 ranges that I would like to look at.  If the age of a certain order is <30 days, 30-59 days, 60-89 days, or greater than 90 days.  I would like to create a countif statement that adds the number of orders that fall in each of the ranges and return that count.

Here is what I have right now.

=COUNTIF('Open Sales Orders'!AH2:AH484,"<"&30)

Comment: So you want one formula to do multiple counting and produce multiple results? Don't think that's really possible by one formula alone.

Comment: But, perhaps you can try Pivot Table ... can you share some sample data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `COUNTIF` will work for <30, although I'd write it slightly differently

`=COUNTIF('Open Sales Orders'!AH2:AH484,"<30")`

and you can do similar for the largest values

`=COUNTIF('Open Sales Orders'!AH2:AH484,">=90")`

for the `between` conditions use COUNTIFS (with an "S") which allows multiple conditions, e.g.

`=COUNTIFS('Open Sales Orders'!AH2:AH484,">=30",'Open Sales Orders'!AH2:AH484,"<60")`

and

`=COUNTIFS('Open Sales Orders'!AH2:AH484,">=60",'Open Sales Orders'!AH2:AH484,"<90")`